# What is the term for a list of people who have permission to access your data?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I was going to wrote a code to display notice to user if the process to download a list of people who has permission to access the current user's data, like this:

> "Unable to load *permission list*"

But then I felt it weird. But to write it fully as:

> "Unable to load *a list of people who has permission to access your
>   data*"

also feel too long and too verbose.

Is there any shorter and better alternative to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The term *permission list* sounds like a list that contains all possible permissions that one can choose from with regard to a particular system. For example, *a Unix file permission list* would be a list that contains all possible variations one can come up with to specify which users or system processes are granted access to his or her files. If you're at all familiar with Unix systems, this would be a set of permission bits you attach to a file that limits other users' access to it for reasons of security. And that's exactly what an ACL that other people here have been talking about is. I think, in your case, however, these would sound a lot better:

> Unable to load **the trusted users list**.
>
> Unable to load **the authorized users list**.

In the field of information systems, trusted or authorized users would be users who have been given permission to use a certain functionality of the system by granting them a set of permissions that allow them to do that.

Comment: I think I will use the trusted users list, as it's the most appropriate for my context. Thanks!

Comment: @ChenLiYong You could even leave the "list" off the end

Answer (score 8):

With respect to a computer file system an **access control list (ACL)** specifies which users or system processes are granted access to objects, as well as what operations are allowed on given objects. ([The source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).)

Comment: Access control list is an awesome term, but too technical for my context. I'll keep in mind though for future usage. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You could also use **Whitelist**

[Definition from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelisting)